# Publish SBT project to local directory

Tags: maven, sbt

I am trying to publish some of my SBT projects on my personal webserver. As far as I know you usually export a SBT project as a Maven directory including a POM.xml, that contains the project definitions.

As [Brian Clapper pointed out](http://brizzled.clapper.org/blog/2010/05/07/sbt-and-your-own-maven-repository/), you can publish such a Maven repository by creating several configuration files and using `sbt publish`. In his tutorial, the repository is transferred via FTP.

I want to push my Maven repository to the server manually so I have more control. Can you give me some hints, how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I figured out how you can do this. This solution creates a local Ivy repository, which is compatible with Maven.

You have to set the following values in your `build.sbt`:

```scala
name := "project-name"

organization := "org.example"

version := "0.0.0"

scalaVersion := "2.9.2"

publishTo := Some(Resolver.file("file", new File("/path/to/your/releases"))
```

After that, you can publish your release

```
sbt publish
```

This will print something like the following lines

```
[info] Set current project to project-name (in build file:/path/to/your/project/)
[info] Updating {file:/path/to/your/project/}default-2e51ea...
[info] Packaging /path/to/your/project/target/scala-2.9.2/project-name_2.9.2-0.0.0-S
NAPSHOT-sources.jar ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.9.2 ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Done updating.
[info] :: delivering :: org.example#project-name_2.9.2;0.0.0 :: 0.0.0 :: release :: Tue Jul 24 15:41:04 CEST 2012
[info]  delivering ivy file to /path/to/your/project/target/scala-2.9.2/ivy-0.0.0.xml
[info] Wrote /path/to/your/project/target/scala-2.9.2/project-name_2.9.2-0.0.0.pom
[info] Packaging /path/to/your/project/target/scala-2.9.2/project-name_2.9.2-0.0.0.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info]  published project-name_2.9.2 to /path/to/your/releases/org/example/project-name_2.9.2/0.0.0-SNAPSHOT/project-name_2.9.2-0.0.0.pom
[info]  published project-name_2.9.2 to /path/to/your/releases/org/example/project-name_2.9.2/0.0.0-SNAPSHOT/project-name_2.9.2-0.0.0.jar
[info]  published project-name_2.9.2 to /path/to/your/releases/org/example/project-name_2.9.2/0.0.0-SNAPSHOT/project-name_2.9.2-0.0.0-sources.jar
[info]  published project-name_2.9.2 to /path/to/your/releases/org/example/project-name_2.9.2/0.0.0-SNAPSHOT/project-name_2.9.2-0.0.0-javadoc.jar
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed 24.07.2012 15:41:05
```

You can put the generated files on any web server (e.g. http://repo.example.org/) and use it in the build script of another project by adding the following lines to your `build.sbt`:

```
resolvers += "Personal repository" at "http://repo.example.org/"

libraryDependencies += "org.example" % "project-name" % "0.0.0"
```

For more information, see [SBT: Getting Started Library Dependencies](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Getting-Started-Library-Dependencies) and [SBT: Publishing](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Publishing).

Answer (score 8):

From sbt, you can use

```
project myproject
[myproject] $ publish-local
```

Which will publish to your local ivy directory (usually `~/.ivy2/local`).

In the output you will see the paths of all the files:

```
[info] Done packaging.
[info] published myproject_2.9.1 to .../ivy2/...myproject.../poms/myproject_2.9.1.pom
[info] published myproject_2.9.1 to .../ivy2/...myproject.../jars/myproject_2.9.1.jar
[info] published myproject_2.9.1 to .../ivy2/...myproject.../srcs/myproject_2.9.1-sources.jar
[info] published myproject_2.9.1 to .../ivy2/...myproject.../docs/myproject_2.9.1-javadoc.jar
[info] published ivy to .../ivy2/...myproject.../ivys/ivy.xml
```

Then you can grab those files and upload them to your ftp server.

I would still recommend the approach described in the linked blogpost though. At least that's how we do it. Just a small note on storing credentials. Use the following sbt setting:

```
val credentials = Credentials(Path.userHome / ".ivy2" / ".my-credentials")
```

The credentials file will look like this:

```
realm=Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager
host=nexus.example.com
user=deployment
password=pass
```

The credentials are the same you use for logging in to the Nexus web interface.

Comment: But this creates an Ivy repository, not a Maven repo. Are there any benefits that come with an Ivy repository? I also don’t plan to use Sonatype Nexus, so the credentials part is irrelevant for me.

Comment: The generated POM file looks like a Maven POM XML. Aren't they compatible?

Comment: Please let me know if it worked. Ivy + Nexus + automatic publishing by sbt is the only setup I'm using.

Comment: In the meantime I switched to Gradle, which has better documentation and Scala support is pretty good. Also, it’s much easier to publish Maven-repos. http://maven.vorb.de/ When I have more time, I'll check, if the directory structure of Ivy works also with Maven and Gradle.

Comment: It worked pretty well using `publishTo` and a file resolver: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11632776/432354