# Using a library from github not existing in mvn repository

Tags: scala, maven, github

There is a Scala library for redis https://github.com/debasishg/scala-redis. It doesn't exist in mvnrepository.com. It's even not written at github how I must use it (add it as a dependency).

So how do  I do that, how do I do add it as a dependency in my project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the `scala-redis`' [SBT Project file](https://github.com/debasishg/scala-redis/blob/master/project/ScalaRedisProject.scala), it's recorded as `redisclient`. Searching for the same in maven sonatype, I get this [result](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.debasishg/redisclient_2.10/2.10). Assuming you're using `scala-2.10` - if not, you can see the list of released builds for other versions [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.debasishg).

Comment: that's what I need. However, if there wasn't such a file `ScalaRedisProject.scala`, how could I use this project? I could download the project and ... what how would I use it as a local project?

Comment: Well, if there were no `pom.xml`, `build.xml` or even a `build.sbt`, you can always create a new `build.sbt` or `pom.xml` yourself. For maven, you can use [maven-archetype-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/usage.html) and do a `mvn install`. Or if you use SBT, it's pretty easy too, just add a `build.sbt` to top level directory and do a `publish-local`. See this [SO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11348670/205936) for details.