# SBT PublishLocal: How to set project version to the published jar and pom insted Scala version

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager

How to set project version to the pom and jar's on SBT PublishLocal or publish

Here is my build.sbt

> ```
> name := "prysm-solution"
>
> version in ThisBuild := "2.0.1.44"
>
> lazy val common_settings = Defaults.coreDefaultSettings ++
>   Seq(
>     organization := "com.reactore.prysm",
>     scalaVersion := "2.12.8",
>     scalacOptions ++= Seq("-unchecked", "-feature", "-deprecation"),
>     updateOptions := updateOptions.value.withLatestSnapshots(false)
>   )
>
> lazy val `prysm-services` = project.in(file("prysm-services")).withId("prysm-services")
>   .settings(common_settings, libraryDependencies ++= Dependencies.deps)
>
>
> retrieveManaged := true
>
> enablePlugins(PackPlugin)
>
> compileOrder := CompileOrder.Mixed
> ```

and published result is

> ...ivy2\local\com.reactore.prysm\prysm-services_2.12\2.0.1.44-PRYSM1-SOLUTION-SNAPSHOT\poms\prysm-services_2.12.pom
>
> ...ivy2\local\com.reactore.prysm\prysm-services_2.12\2.0.1.44-PRYSM1-SOLUTION-SNAPSHOT\jars\prysm-services_2.12.jar

**`How can i publish like`**

> ...ivy2\local\com.reactore.prysm\prysm-services_2.12\2.0.1.44-PRYSM1-SOLUTION-SNAPSHOT\poms\prysm-services_2.0.1.44.pom
>
> ...ivy2\local\com.reactore.prysm\prysm-services_2.12\2.0.1.44-PRYSM1-SOLUTION-SNAPSHOT\jars\prysm-services_2.0.1.44.jar

Comment: I think your question may have already been answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11348670/publish-sbt-project-to-local-directory

Comment: It might also help to add the configuration:   publishMavenStyle: = true